# Method error. Method cannot be applied to given types. Required: Double, Found: No arguments

Tags: methods, static-methods

I have an assigment that requires me to read data off a .txt containing gravity levels and then calculate your weight on each planet using methods. There seems to be an issue in the first method with type values? I canno tell. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
  /**
  * Description for 7.04 Weight project
  *
  `* @author (Your Name)
   * @version (The Date)
      import java.util.Scanner;
      import java.io.File;
       import java.io.IOException;

        public class Weight
     {
// write static methods here
// Note: formula for finding weight on a planet:  Earth weight divided by Gravity constant times surface gravity
public static void getGravity(double [] gravity)throws IOException
{
    File fileName = new File("gravity.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
    int i = 0;
    while(inFile.hasNext())
    {
        gravity[i] = inFile.nextDouble();


    }

}
public static void printResults(String[] name, double gravity[] ,double[] weight)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <=8; i++)
    {
      System.out.printf("  %-7s         %3.1f            %7s", name[i], gravity[i] , weight[i]);
    }
}
public static double[] calcWeight(double [] gravity)
{
    double myWeight = 100.0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        gravity[i] = gravity[i] * myWeight;

    }
    return gravity;





}
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{

    // Extension idea... instead of hard codeing the weight, you may propt the user for input.

    double earthWeight = 100.0; // initalize Earth weight to 100 lbs.

    String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
    double[] gravity = getGravity();                            // static method you write
    double[] weight = calcWeight(earthWeight, gravity);  // static method you write
    printResults(names, gravity, weight);                   // static method you write

} //end main
```

}//end class

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
calcWeight(earthWeight, gravity); //passes two parameters

public static double[] calcWeight(double [] gravity) //takes one paramter
```

The method call does not match the method definition.

Comment: I suppose thats one problem but I haven't gotten to it yet. the error I am getting is in the double []gravity = getGravity(); Line

Comment: `public static void getGravity(double [] gravity)` takes one parameter and you're passing zero.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: ...Pass `gravity` to it.  You also want to remove the `gravity =` part because that method doesn't return anything.  See also [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)